# How do I allow all Cross Domain Requests on my Django Rest Framework project?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

I have tried the following things:

- Installed [Djagno Cors Headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) and added the following code to my **settings**:

  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
- I have also added csrf_exempt handlers to all my API views.

Yet, nothing works and I still keep on getting CSRF errors. Any help? What am exactly doing wrong. The exact same code was working on my local server, yet now its broken :/

Even GET requests don't work, which is just odd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@csrf_exempt just use for POST method.

you can remove @csrf_exempt which above GET api.